# How to access AssignedTo in JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have a task list that has a field AssigneTo which takes a user via the people picker. I can get the list item I need but I have no idea how I would access the oject being returned for the AssignedTo field.

I have tried

```
var theUser = listItem.get_item('AssignedTo')
alert(theUser.get_loginName());
```

and just using

```
 listItem.get_item('AssignedTo').toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listItem.get_item('AssignedTo').get_lookupValue();
```